# "No system SSH available" error on OpenShift rhc snapshot save on Windows 8

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

**Steps To Replicate**

On Windows 8.

In shell (with SSH connection active):

```
rhc snapshot save [appname]
```

**Error**

`No system SSH available. Please use the --ssh option to specify the path to your SSH executable, or install SSH.`

**Suggested Solution**

From [this post](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/ssh-executabledoes-not-exist#comment-37555):

```
Usage: rhc snapshot-save <application> [--filepath FILE] [--ssh path_to_ssh_executable]
Pass '--help' to see the full list of options
```

**Question**

The path to keys on PC is:

```
C:\Users\[name]\.ssh
```

How do I define this in the rhc snaphot command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

```
rhc snapshot save [appname] --filepath FILE --ssh "C:\Users\[name]\.ssh"
```

This will show the message:

```
Pulling down a snapshot of application '[appname]' to FILE ...
... then after a while
Pulling down a snapshot of application '[appname]' to FILE ... DONE
```

**Update**

That saved the backup in a file called "FILE" without an extension, so I'm guessing in the future I should define the filename as something like "my_app_backup.tar.gz" ie:

```
rhc snapshot save [appname] --filepath "my_app_backup.tar.gz" --ssh "C:\Users\[name]\.ssh"
```

It will save in the repo directory, so make sure you move it out of this directory before you git add, commit, push etc, otherwise you will upload your backup too.